# Check button color in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I wrote the following function to  verify a button color with C# selenium web driver, but it returns `false` and don't know what the problem is:

```
public Boolean check_source_button_color()
{
    Boolean Cond1 = false;

    try
    {
        String headerColor = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[13]/div/a"))
            .GetCssValue("background-color");

        if (Assert.Equals("#15688f", headerColor))    
        {
            Cond1 = true;
        }
    }
    catch { };

    return Cond1;
}
```

And in the issue I call it

```
if (Req_det_page.check_source_button_color())
{
    Cond3 = true;
}
```

Cond3 always false.

Comment: I think your code may be jumping to the catch clause.
Would you mind to share the stacktrace? That would give a clue of what could be your problem and guide us to help you.

Comment: Add something like catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}

Comment: What happens when you step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: After I've put exception message in the catch I found that there is a problem in the string format and also the header color was rgba value so comparison with hex value was false.

Comment: So, I've searched for a function to convert rgba to hex value and made some changes in code, and finally it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot @acarlstein and Rufus L, I'll put the code in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code after editing and it works well.

```
   public Boolean check_source_button_color()
        {
            Boolean Cond1 = false;
            try
            {
                string headerColor = (driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Go to regulatory source website")).GetCssValue("background-color"));

                String[] hexValue = headerColor.Replace("rgba(", "").Replace(")", "").Split(',');

                hexValue[0] = hexValue[0].Trim();

                int hexValue1 = int.Parse(hexValue[0]);

                hexValue[1] = hexValue[1].Trim();

                int hexValue2 = int.Parse(hexValue[1]);

                hexValue[2]  = hexValue[2].Trim();

                int hexValue3 = int.Parse(hexValue[2]);

                hexValue[3] = hexValue[3].Trim();

                int hexValue4 = int.Parse(hexValue[3]);

                String actualColor = String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", hexValue1, hexValue2, hexValue3);

                Console.WriteLine( headerColor);
                Console.WriteLine("actualColor is " + actualColor);

                if (actualColor.Equals("#1e95ce"))
                {
                    Cond1 = true;
                }

                }
            catch (System.Exception ex )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return Cond1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
public string ConvertCssColorToHex(string cssColor)
{
    const string pattern = @"^rgba\((\d{1,3}),\s*(\d{1,3}),\s*(\d{1,3}),\s*(\d{1,3})\)$";
    
    return new Regex(pattern).Replace(cssColor, m => {
        return "#"
            + int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value).ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0')
            + int.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value).ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0')
            + int.Parse(m.Groups[3].Value).ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0');
    });
}
```